# How do I keep icon disabled if the icon value in constructor is null on RaisedButton.icon()?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a common widget for buttons that takes icon value as a constructor. Sometimes I would like the widget to have no icon visible. How do I put that logic in a widget looking like this?

```
const SocialAuthBtn({this.action, this.title, this.textColor, this.bgColor, this.icon});

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: double.infinity,
      height: UtilWidget.verticalBlock(7),
      child: RaisedButton.icon(
          onPressed: action,
          color: bgColor,
          label: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: UtilWidget.horizontalBlock(2)),
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal + 10,
                color: textColor,
                height: 1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          icon: Image.asset(
            icon,
            width: UtilWidget.horizontalBlock(4),
            height: UtilWidget.horizontalBlock(4),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try,

```
icon: icon!=null? Image.asset(
            icon,
            width: UtilWidget.horizontalBlock(4),
            height: UtilWidget.horizontalBlock(4),
          ):Icon(null)
```

Comment: it's not completely correct because the icon is only hidden but the space is busy for this icon hidden

Comment: Yes, you're right. Do you know another way?

Comment: Use Container() instead of Icon(null). otherwise empty space will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you can check if the item is null or not and then assign it to widget's icon:

```
icon: this.icon != null ? 
          Image.asset(
            icon,
            width: UtilWidget.horizontalBlock(4),
            height: UtilWidget.horizontalBlock(4),
          ) : 
          Icon(null);
```

Comment: Your answer will throw Failed assertion:  'icon != null': is not true.

Comment: replace the null part with `Icon(null)` or any other widget like a `Container`

Answer (score 1):

Flutter internally follows this approach

```
icon: iconValue == null? null
: Icon(
 prefixIcon,
 color: prefixIconColor,
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
When pass icon null return Container() 
You can see demo work for both condition 

code snippet

```
class SocialAuthBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback action;
  final String title;
  final Color textColor;
  final Color bgColor;
  final String icon;

  const SocialAuthBtn({this.action, this.title, this.textColor, this.bgColor, this.icon});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: double.infinity,
      height: 100, //UtilWidget.verticalBlock(7),
      child: RaisedButton.icon(
          onPressed: action,
          color: bgColor,
          label: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                color: textColor,
                height: 1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          icon: icon == null ? Container() : Image.asset(
            icon,
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SocialAuthBtn(action: (){print("ok");},title: "title",textColor: Colors.blue, bgColor: Colors.white, icon: 'assets/images/alarm.png'),
            SocialAuthBtn(action: (){print("ok");},title: "title",textColor: Colors.blue, bgColor: Colors.white, icon: null),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class SocialAuthBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback action;
  final String title;
  final Color textColor;
  final Color bgColor;
  final String icon;

  const SocialAuthBtn({this.action, this.title, this.textColor, this.bgColor, this.icon});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: double.infinity,
      height: 100, //UtilWidget.verticalBlock(7),
      child: RaisedButton.icon(
          onPressed: action,
          color: bgColor,
          label: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                color: textColor,
                height: 1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          icon: icon == null ? Container() : Image.asset(
            icon,
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```